# Stacked Circular Barplot in python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I'm quite new to python, and I would like to create a stacked circular barplot: something similar to the one in the picture:

[image]

The code for that I found for R, which I know even less about :

```
# library
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
  value1=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value2=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value3=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Transform data in a tidy format (long format)
data <- data %>% gather(key = "observation", value="value", -c(1,2)) 

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
nObsType <- nlevels(as.factor(data$observation))
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group)*nObsType, ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar*nObsType )
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group, individual)
data$id <- rep( seq(1, nrow(data)/nObsType) , each=nObsType)

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data %>% group_by(id, individual) %>% summarize(tot=sum(value))
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data) +      

  # Add the stacked bar
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +

  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 100, xend = start, yend = 100), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 150, xend = start, yend = 150), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 200, xend = start, yend = 200), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200") , color="grey", size=6 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  ylim(-150,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +

  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)


# Save at png
ggsave(p, file="output.png", width=10, height=10)
```

My data is set up like this :

[image]

Is there any way to do this in python? In my case what you see as ABCD in the picture would be the maingroup1-3. The stack would be the percentage datas. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using matplotlib.pyplot, but actually achieving a result similar to the picture you've shown can be quite tricky...

I'll just quickly show an example of what can be done. Results aren't nearly as beautiful as your picture but it's just to give you some hints on how you could achieve this. You would of course have to adapt your data to it as I generated random data for this plot...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set number of bars
n = 36

# generate random data
r = [[np.random.randint(0, 10)]*int(360/n) for i in range(n)]
r = [x for l in r for x in l]
theta = list(range(360))
theta = [2 * np.pi * (x/360) for x in theta]

# add last coordinate to the end of the list
r = r + [r[0]]
theta = theta + [theta[0]]

# initialize axes
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

# plot theta and r
ax.plot(theta, r)

# set ticks and borders
ax.set_rmax(10)
ax.set_rticks([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

# show grid
ax.grid(True)

# set center to empty (like a donut plot)
ax.set_rorigin(-5)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('W', offset=20)

plt.show()
```

What it gives is something like this:

[image]